# PyQt5: How to input default value if QLineEdit is empty?

Tags: python, excel, user-interface, pyqt5, qlineedit

I have already associated my PyQt5 Gui with Excel.

I would like to input '2000' into Excel via PyQt5 Gui program even if I do not input anything on it.

The explanation photo is below:

[image]

even if I do not input anything in PyQt5 Gui,

[image]

'2000' should be typed in Excel.

However, the point is if anything input in PyQt5 Gui, it should be written in Excel as it was written on PyQt5.

The code that I made is below:

```
class Ship_Use_Tug_Input_Program(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        visbl = QLabel('Visibility(m)', self)
        visbl.move(60, 450)
        vis_ent = QLineEdit(self)
        vis_ent.move(180, 445)

        file = pathlib.Path('C:/Users/woody/OneDrive/Desktop/Python Workspace/Ship_Use_Tug_Input_Program.xlsx')
        if file.exists():
            pass
        else:
            file=Workbook()
            sheet = file.active

        file.save('C:/Users/woody/OneDrive/Desktop/Python Workspace/Ship_Use_Tug_Input_Program.xlsx')

    def save_to_excel(self):
        file = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/woody/OneDrive/Desktop/Python Workspace/Ship_Use_Tug_Input_Program.xlsx')

        sheet = file.active
        sheet.cell(column=10, row=sheet.max_row, value=vis_ent.text())

        file.save('C:/Users/woody/OneDrive/Desktop/Python Workspace/Ship_Use_Tug_Input_Program.xlsx')

    btn_save = QPushButton('S a v e', self)
    btn_save.clicked.connect(save_to_excel)
    btn_save.move(400,510)

    self.setWindowTitle('Ship use tug input program')
    self.setFixedSize(945, 570)
    self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ship_Use_Tug_Input_Program()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always add widgets as attributes, so you can access them in other methods:

```
class Ship_Use_Tug_Input_Program(QWidget):
    ...    
    def initUI(self):
        self.visbl = QLabel('Visibility(m)', self)
        self.visbl.move(60, 450)
        self.vis_ent = QLineEdit(self)
        self.vis_ent.move(180, 445)
```

Now you can get the input text:

```
    def save_to_excel(self):
        ...    
        sheet = file.active
        value = self.vis_ent.text().strip() or '2000'
        sheet.cell(column=10, row=sheet.max_row, value=value)
        ...
```

If `vis_ent` is empty or whitespace-only, the default value will be used instead.

---

**UPDATE**:

Here is what your whole class should look like:

```
class Ship_Use_Tug_Input_Program(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.visbl = QLabel('Visibility(m)', self)
        self.visbl.move(60, 450)
        self.vis_ent = QLineEdit(self)
        self.vis_ent.move(180, 445)

        self.btn_save = QPushButton('S a v e', self)
        self.btn_save.clicked.connect(self.save_to_excel)
        self.btn_save.move(400, 510)

        self.setWindowTitle('Ship use tug input program')
        self.setFixedSize(945, 570)
        self.show()

        file = pathlib.Path('C:/Users/woody/OneDrive/Desktop/Python Workspace/Ship_Use_Tug_Input_Program.xlsx')
        if file.exists():
            pass
        else:
            file=Workbook()
            sheet = file.active

        file.save('C:/Users/woody/OneDrive/Desktop/Python Workspace/Ship_Use_Tug_Input_Program.xlsx')

    def save_to_excel(self):
        file = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/woody/OneDrive/Desktop/Python Workspace/Ship_Use_Tug_Input_Program.xlsx')
        sheet = file.active
        value = self.vis_ent.text().strip() or '2000'
        sheet.cell(column=10, row=sheet.max_row, value=value)

        file.save('C:/Users/woody/OneDrive/Desktop/Python Workspace/Ship_Use_Tug_Input_Program.xlsx')
```

Comment: sir, there is an error named below.
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "c:/Users/woody/OneDrive/바탕 화면/Python Workspace/0. 연습/practice.py", line 33, in save_to_excel
    value = self.vis_ent.text().strip() or '2000'
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'vis_ent'

Comment: @WoodyKim There are some other errors in your example code. You need to put all the setup code inside `initUI`. See my updated answer for a complete solution. (PS: if you found this answer useful, please upvote/accept).

Comment: sir, I have solved as your solution. Thank you very much SIR!! :))